# Systemd service exits with "success" but does not perform the .sh script at ExecStart

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, shell-script, systemd

I'm trying to use a systemd service on a Raspberry Pi (running Raspberry Pi OS version
"Bullseye", a flavor of Debian) to run a bash script on login and it seems to succeed but the script doesn't seem to be running. The bash script works perfectly when I run it directly. What is going on?

---

**Here's the systemd service** (`/lib/systemd/system/kiosk.service`)

```
[Unit]
Description=Chromium Kiosk
Wants=graphical.target
After=graphical.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 20
Environment=DISPLAY=:0.0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/pi/kiosk.sh
Restart=on-abort
User=pi
Group=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

- I confirmed the display id is correct via `echo $DISPLAY` returning `0` (only one display connected)
- "ExecStartPre" command will just pause execution for 20 seconds
- I confirmed XAUTHORITY location with `echo $XAUTHORITY`
- I confirmed the default and only user's username is "pi"
- I confirmed /home/pi/kiosk.sh file path
- I gave the kiosk.sh file permissions with `chmod u+x ~/kiosk.sh`

**And here's the kiosk.sh file** (which works perfectly, just including here for context/MVCE):

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script has been adapted from: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-kiosk/

# Disable screensaver / blank screen due to inactivity
xset s noblank
xset s off
xset -dpms

# Hide mouse cursor using the unclutter program
unclutter -idle 0.5 -root &

# Make sure chrome doesnt open any prompts when it opens (i.e., no crash report prompt after being force quitted)
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' /home/$USER/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exit_type":"Crashed"/"exit_type":"Normal"/' /home/$USER/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences

# Launch chromium with our params
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk https://example.com/ &
```

---

When I do `sudo systemctl startkiosk.service`, then wait for it to finish, nothing happens, and when I do `sudo systemctl status kiosk.service` I get this:

```
● kiosk.service - Chromium Kiosk
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kiosk.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2022-11-01 19:33:24 GMT; 6s ago
    Process: 1930 ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 20 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1932 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/pi/kiosk.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1932 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 96ms
 
Nov 01 17:27:04 test-hostname systemd[1]: Starting Chromium Kiosk...
Nov 01 17:27:24 test-hostname systemd[1]: Started Chromium Kiosk.
Nov 01 17:27:24 test-hostname systemd[1]: kiosk.service: Succeeded.
```

Why isn't the bash script executing even though it executes fine when called directly?

Comment: I tend to put `touch` commands between other commands to see what gets called. However, I assume the script is failing to run the browser. Since you have put it into the background, your script has no way of telling if it has failed. In all likelyhood, the script will have finished and existed before the browser has started and run to a point of failure. You also cannot be certain that the X desktop is fully up and running to a point where it will begin to accept clients. If you want to start a browser on login, there are far better ways that enabling a systemd unit.

Comment: Thanks @Bib. What about launching chromium would differ between executing the kiosk.sh from the systemd service versus running kiosk.sh directly? It works when running directly. As per the desktop not being fully up and running, there is a 20 second delay and regardless, it's moot because still no dice when I manually run the service with `sudo systemctl start kiosk.service` (it still says success and no chromium window)

Comment: Then don't put it into the background as a test. Sprinkle `touch` commands within the script to see how far it gets. You can also enable `-x` within the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why isn't the bash script executing even though it executes fine when called directly?

The status output doesn't confirm your theory – it says that the script *was* started, and that it quickly *exited.* And indeed the way your script is written, it does not wait for Chromium to finish, but spawns it using `&` and immediately exits afterwards. **That's what the `&` does.**

But because you have `Type=simple`, systemd expects the *initial* process (i.e. the shell script) to run basically forever. When it exits, that's taken as an indication of the service stopping on its own – the .service unit is accordingly marked as stopped and all leftover processes are immediately cleaned up, i.e. your Chromium browser gets killed before it gets a chance to display anything.

Often, if the service leaves *one* child process that can be unambiguously identified as the "main process" (either by using a PID file or by letting systemd guess), `Type=forking` is more appropriate – with it, systemd will wait for the main child to exit instead.

In your case though, there are at least two processes (chromium and unclutter) at the same level of hierarchy, so you need the script itself to remain as the "main process" – keep `Type=simple` but remove the `&` after the Chromium invocation, so that the script process will last as long as Chromium does.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. I simply removed the ampersand and it works. I was thinking in terms of batch scripting where the ampersand would work like `start` and spawn a new process for the chromium stuff.